# Rational pair of solutions to $\sec(\pi r_1)+\sec(\pi r_2)=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, trigonometry

Given the equation $$\sec(\pi r_1)+\sec(\pi r_2)=2$$ I could numerically verify (for a denominater smaller than $2^8$) that the only rational pair of solutions in the interval $0<r_1\leq r_2\leq1$ is $(r_1,r_2)=(\frac{2}{5},\frac{4}{5})$. Now I want to prove this somehow.

The statement is equivalent to asking for which values of $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the three values $\sec(\pi r_1),\sec(\pi r_2)$, $1$ linearly dependent. I know a similar theorem for cosines (namely one by [Berger](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.06652.pdf)) but could not figure out how to use it for my problem. Any help, such as similar papers, is appreciated.

Edit: Do theorems regarding the linear independence of inverses— i.e. if $\alpha,\beta,1$ are lin. indep. we can determine something about the lin. indep. of $\frac{1}{\alpha},\frac{1}{\beta},1$— exist?

Edit 2: I found some papers regarding linear independence of trigonometric functions, however, I do not see if and how to apply them: [Paper 1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225442316_Rational_values_of_the_arccosine_function), [Paper 2](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Algebraic-trigonometric-values-at-rational-of-%CF%80-Tangsupphathawat/ed624d93c0a5af9bc06f2148e2d3b217e3379d90), [Paper 3](https://eudml.org/doc/155256)

Comment: You have infinitely many solutions, for example $(r_1,r_2)=(\pm \frac{2}{5}+2m, \pm \frac{4}{5}+2n)$, $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @GreginGre good point, let me clarify my question